# Can Tkinter OptionMenu have variable size and options?

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I am connecting to an email server and getting the number and names of 'folders' that are currently in use. Is it possible for *values (from tutorial code (1)) to be a list of StringVar objects? I have a list of StringVar objects that I want to dynamically update into the OptionMenu based on input from a server. So I am adding a dynamic list of StringVar objects and then trying to have them populate in the OptionMenu. I think the problem is that StringVar are objects and not text values, which is why it's not populating the OptionMenu. Is there a way to fix this?

Tutorial Code (1):

```
from Tkinter import *

# the constructor syntax is:
# OptionMenu(master, variable, *values)

OPTIONS = [
    "egg",
    "bunny",
    "chicken"
]

master = Tk()

variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default value

w = apply(OptionMenu, (master, variable) + tuple(OPTIONS))
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

Populating a list of StringVar objects (from another tutorial):

```
if resp == 'OK':
                    for mbox in data:
                        flags, separator, name = self.parse_mailbox(bytes.decode(mbox))
                        fmt = '{0}    : [Flags = {1}; Separator = {2}'
                        fmt = '{0}'
                        if not "/ [Gmail]" in fmt.format(name):
                            temp = tk.StringVar()
                            temp.set(fmt.format(name))
                            self.list.append(temp)
```

Adding to OptionMenu Code:

```
variable = tk.StringVar(self)
        variable.set("INBOX") #defaultvalue

        tk.Label(self, text="Choose Mailbox: ").grid(row=1,sticky='W',padx=30,pady=10, columnspan=1)
        self.mailboxes = tk.OptionMenu(self, variable, *self.controller.list)
        #self.mailboxes = apply(OptionMenu, (self, variable) + tuple(self.controller.list))
        self.mailboxes.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='W',pady=10, columnspan=1)
```

Thank you for reading.

*Edit* Updated 'append' code to get StringVar() value and place into list

```
if not "/ [Gmail]" in fmt.format(name):
                            temp = tk.StringVar()
                            temp.set(fmt.format(name))
                            self.list.append(temp.get())
```

Also updated OptionMenu initilization

```
    self.mailboxes = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.variable, *self.controller.list)
```

Here is the error message:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1Uye.png

Comment: Have you tried to use `temp.get()` in your `self.list.append` function?

Comment: @jimbob88 thank you for the suggestion. I just tried it and at line "self.mailboxes = tk.OptionMenu(self, variable, tuple(self.controller.list))" it returned a blank box. The original line gave me an error because it said it was "missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'"

Comment: I believe this is because you pass a tuple, you should pass an extrapolation of the list: https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/optionmenu.htm off the top of my head you should use `*self.controller.list` instead of `tuple ()`

Comment: @jimbob88 yes, that's the tutorial link I'm using. I updated with the info you suggested, but I got the 'missing 1 required positional argument: 'value' error. The post has been edited to include the information you suggested and a link to the error image. This is part of why I got stuck and tried to use tuple() instead.

Comment: I believe the error you are showing, too me, does not look like an Option Menu error, but instead an  `__innit_` error, have you not parsed the variable `value`  to your in it perhaps? But not looking at the full code I could not make a better guess